# Javascript Timer for a maze game

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone I was wondering how to put a timer into javascript that will count up.  I am trying to make a maze game that counts the time that it takes for a user to get to the finish however I can't figure it out.  If you have any suggestions let me know, thanks.

Comment: Read that nice post about [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) before asking next time.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` when the game is done. You set the `setInterval` inside of a variable so you can later reference it in `clearInterval`

```
// Increase the game timer by 1 second
var gameTimer = window.setInterval(function() {

    // Increase your timer here

}, 1000);


// Clears timer
function clearTimer() {
    clearInterval(gameTimer)
}
```

Comment: @jmoods24 No problem - If this helped, please mark this as the correct answer :)